# WindowsError: [Error2] The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

I expect the program to open the link specified and then close the browser after some time.REPEAT this task 3 times.
But I end up getting the mentioned error.

```
import time
import subprocess
total_breaks = 3
break_count = 0
print("This program started on " + time.ctime())
while(break_count < total_breaks):
    browser = subprocess.Popen(['firefox', 'https://www.google.com/'])
    sleep(10)
    browser.terminate()
    break_count = break_count + 1
```

Comment: Hi Vivek, no need to shout here (`#`); everyone is getting heard/read/seen :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the path to firefox Just like the error shows:

> WindowsError: [Error2] The system cannot find the file specified

```
subprocess.Popen([r'C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\Firefox.exe',
'-new-tab', 'http://www.google.com/'])
```